# Adding items to the manager menu in Piranha CMS

Tags: piranha-cms

Following the PiranhaCMS 2.2.0 documentation does not insert the menu items into the Manager menu.

What am I doing wrong?

I've placed this in my **_AppStart.cshtml**

```
Manager.Menu.Add(new Manager.MenuGroup()
    {
        InternalId = "MyApp",
        Name = "My app",
        CssClass = "fancy-icon"
    });

/* From this point down - also tried placing in _ViewStart.cshtml */
Manager.Menu.Where(m => m.InternalId == "MyApp").Single().Items.Add(
  new Manager.MenuItem() {
    Name = "Products",
    Action = "productlist",
    Controller = "products",
    Permission = "ADMIN_PRODUCT",
    SelectedActions = "productlist,productedit"
  });

Manager.Menu.Where(m => m.InternalId == "MyApp").Single().Items.Add(
  new Manager.MenuItem() {
    Name = "Product groups",
    Action = "productgrouplist",
    Controller = "products",
    Permission = "ADMIN_PRODUCTGROUP",
    SelectedActions = "productgrouplist,productgroupedit"
  });
```

However, even though the code is hit, and I can see that the `Manager.Menu` has the new items in it - they don't render in the Manager Menu.

What am I missing here? Where should I place the actual Menu inserts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code above seems pretty much copied from the example at http://piranhacms.org/docs/extend/manager-menu. If you take a look at the last paragraph in the documentation you can see that in the above example two **custom permissions** have been added for the new manager functions (ADMIN_PRODUCT, ADMIN_PRODUCTGROUP).

Since the manager only renders items accessible by the logged in user I can only assume that you haven't added these permissions under System > Permissions which results in the current user **not** have access to them. And since the user hasn't access to any items in the group, the entire group is hidden!

Just remove the `Permission = "..."` from you items and they should render.

Regards

Håkan

Comment: Great! I misread the docs, I thought _"By specifying the selected actions for both of these two menu items we have ensured that the right one will be highlighted in the menu. We've also added to new permissions for the two menu items that we can set up in the manager interface."_ The way it reads I foolishly assumed it would create the permissions if they couldn't be found. Thank you Håkan.